# How to ensure sql server full text catalog is always up to date?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-catalog

My full text catalog is not always up to date and my solution at the moment is to right click on the catalog and click Rebuild. I triied repopulating and it does not fix the problem. Only a rebuild works.  Can anyone explain to me why repopulating doesn't work?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the catalog set to track changes. In the catalog properties, go to tables/views and set track changes to automatic.

Comment: @Luaan - Already checked that, it was already set to automatic